# What advantages do Secret Managers offer in terms of authentication [API usage]?

Tags: password-management, key-management

The problem I am seeing with secret managers (programs which serve as a store of secrets for other programs/APIs) is that at some level, a key or credentials must still be provided programmatically, thus the original problem is not fully solved because if that "master" key/creds are transmitted insecurely, stored in source-code, or otherwise compromised, then it compromises the secrets after all.

Can someone who is slightly more educated on the subject matter comment on how secrets managers tackle the authentication problem or otherwise make it more secure over traditional API-key authentication?

Some example systems: Thycotic Secret Server, Amazon Secrets Manager, Hashicorp Vault.

Comment: There's many systems that store credentials.  You're probably best off picking a few and asking about those, otherwise this question is WAY too broad IMO.

Comment: @Daisetsu updated with names of some systems.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the "zero-secret problem" and it is certainly an issue: if you drop in a secret manager but then the credentials for that secret manager are checked into a public git repo, you are **very** hosed.  As a result, a good secret manager will have options for tokenless authentication (or at least, authentication with temporary/transient credentials).  To give some examples:

1. AWS secret manager uses role-based authentication (aka you grant access via policies attached to an IAM role that is attached to your compute resources, so no permanent tokens are required).
2. Hashicorp Vault and [AKeyless](https://www.akeyless.io) can be configured to give compute resources access based on IAM roles that are assigned to them in AWS/GCP/etc...  In this sense, you are relying on the cloud provider as a trusted identity provider, and so get tokenless authentication.
3. With Hashicorp Vault and AKeyless we frequently authenticate our Gitlab pipelines using the JWT provided by Gitlab.  Gitlab signs a JWT for each pipeline, and publishes the public key for everyone.  You can configure the secret manager to fetch the public key and use it to validate the JWT provided by the pipeline.  In essence, this once again relies on Gitlab as a trusted identity provider.  Since the JWTs are short-lived and generated when needed, there is no need to store tokens and very little risk from lost tokens.
4. AKeyless also has "Universal Identity" that is meant to be a more generic solution to the zero-secret problem.  It uses a continuously-rotating token to uniquely identify and authenticate a piece of infrastructure.  Tokens are rotated as often as you want and the old token becomes inactive as soon as a rotation happens, so token lifetimes can be arbitrarily short.

In short: there isn't much point in using a secret manager if you just need another access token to access it.  Fortunately, your secret manager probably has you covered.  You'll have to compare it's features with your use-cases though to find the right option.

Answer (score 1):

Dissociating the secret store from the secret user means that you can be more selective about what secrets are exposed to the secret user. It also means that you have a single place where all your secrets are stored meaning that you don't need to go trawling through the configuration files of lots of services when you want to change secrets.   You can also apply different controls to the secrets - e.g. your database might use a short password to authenticate. But your secret store could use a client certificate to grant access to that password. And you can log the access.

If you rotate the authentication token used for the secret store you reduce the risk of the access being compromised via (e.g.) backups.

There's not much benefit if you have (for example) a single application server needing a single password for a database. But when you have lots of servers needing lots of secrets it saves a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

It always depends how critical is your software.

**Software** 
Yes, most of the times you still have to provide a key or credentials at some point, programmatically, or by giving access to a file only to a specific service and that file contains the secret. If you're choosing any of these ways, it is important to erase the value from the memory as soon as possible (immediately after the authentication if this is your purpose). 
If your purpose is encryption or digital signing, you can always use public key cryptography, give the software the public key (and use that one for encryption/ digital signing) and use somehow else (offline/ stored separately) the private key.

**Hardware**
If you can afford hardware, then a solution might be storing the master secret on a separate device that you are sure enough it won't be compromised, and couple that device to a server in a secure cage/ data-center.